# Entity framework integration in visual studio 2019

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I just installed VS 2019 (my machine didn't have VS 2017) right now I trying to integrate EF without luck.
I need your suggesting how to do so?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the entity framework tools (no perfect translations) tools --> tools and functionalities --> from the vs2019 installer --> single components --> entity framework 6 tools.
Then add the EF6 to your solution from Nuget as usual.